# C# How to remove XPKeywords (PropertyItem 0x9c9e) from an image

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, exif

I was having trouble editing or removing keywords from a photograph. The following works to replace the keywords successfully:

```
...
string s_keywords = "tag1;tag2;tag3";
PropertyItem item_keyword = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
item_keyword.Id = 0x9c9e; // XPKeywords
item_keyword.Type = 1;
item_keyword.Value = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s_keywords + "\0");
item_keyword.Len = item_keyword.Value.Length;
image.SetPropertyItem(item_keyword);
...
```

Note that my experiments show that `image.RemovePropertyItem(0x9c9e);` seems to have no effect on the saved image. Instead use the above code with `s_keywords = "";`

**Don't do it this way:** The following code works to remove the keywords, but results in the jpeg being re-encoded and loosing some quality (the image file goes from about 4MB to < 2MB and I can see some slight visual differences):

```
...
Image image_copy = new Bitmap(image);
foreach (var pi in image.PropertyItems)
{
    if (pi.Id != 0x9c9e) image_copy.SetPropertyItem(pi);
}
image.Dispose();
image = (Image)image_copy.Clone();
...
```

I'm was having similar issues with setting the XPTitle - setting the propertyItem 0x9c9b seemed to have no effect in the saved image, instead I had to open the file as a BitmapFrame, extract the BitmapMetadata and use the Title property, then build a new jpeg using JpegBitmapEncoder - thus re-encoding and loosing image quality.

```
...
BitmapFrame bf_title = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(tmp_file, UriKind.Relative));
BitmapMetadata bmd_title = (BitmapMetadata)bf_title.Metadata.Clone();
bmd_title.Title = new_title;
BitmapFrame bf_new = BitmapFrame.Create(bf_title, bf_title.Thumbnail, bmd_title, bf_title.ColorContexts);
JpegBitmapEncoder je = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
je.Frames.Add(bf_new);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(tmp_file, FileMode.Create);
je.Save(fs);
fs.Close();
...
```

See my answer below for the correct way to change the title.

This was driving me crazy, I hope this can help someone else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the above keywords code now works perfectly.

I'm answering this because I could not find sample code to do this when I searched - so hopefully someone else will find this useful.

To change the title use the following code. The problem was that there are two tags that affect how windows shows the title - one of which (0x010e) takes priority over the XPTitle (0xc9b) tag...

```
...
string new_value = "New title for the image";
PropertyItem item_title = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
item_title.Id = 0x9c9b; // XPTitle 0x9c9b
item_title.Type = 1;
item_title.Value = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(new_value + "\0");
item_title.Len = item_title.Value.Length;
image.SetPropertyItem(item_title);
PropertyItem item_title2 = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
item_title2.Id = 0x010e; // ImageDescription 0x010e
item_title2.Type = 2;
item_title2.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new_value + "\0");
item_title2.Len = item_title2.Value.Length;
image.SetPropertyItem(item_title2);

image.Save("new_filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
image.Dispose();
...
```

Note - Another potential issue, you need to save the image to a new location. You can then dispose of the image and copy it into the original location if desired.